# Difference between `+=` and `<<` inside a block for `each_with_object`

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, immutability

I had to update an array, and I used `+=` and `<<` in different runs of code inside a block passed to `Array#each_with_object`:

#### Code 1

```
(1..5).each_with_object([]) do |i, a|
  puts a.inspect
  a += [i]
end
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

#### Code 2

```
(1..5).each_with_object([]) do |i, a|
  puts a.inspect
  a << [i]
end
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```

The `+=` operator does not update the original array. Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: It is not `Array#each_with_object`. The receiver is a range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `each_with_object`, the so-called memo object is common among the iterations. You need to modify that object in order to do something meaningful. The `+=` operator is syntax sugar for `+` and assignment, which does not modify the receiver, hence the iteration has no effect. If you use methods like `<<` or `push`, then it will have effect.

On the other hand, in `inject`, the so-called memo object is the return value of the block, and you don't need to modify the object, but you need to return the value you want for the next iteration.

Comment: From Jorg's answer, I understand that I am inefficiently creating new array by `+` in each loop run. How ever, I am assigning resulted array to the `memo` object......shouldn't it update the memo object. Instead it feel like, it is creating a new array with same name as `memo` object and not updating the actual `memo` object.

Comment: @HariShankar That is the case with `inject`.

Answer (score 4):

> It is clear to me that += operator is not updating the original array. Why?

Because [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2B) says so (emphasis mine):

> ## `ary + other_ary` → `new_ary`
>
> Concatenation — Returns a **new** array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a **third** array.
>
> ```
> [ 1, 2, 3 ] + [ 4, 5 ]    #=> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
> c = a + [ "d", "e", "f" ]
> c                         #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
> a                         #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
> ```
>
> Note that
>
> ```
> x += y
> ```
>
> is the same as
>
> ```
> x = x + y
> ```
>
> This means that it produces a **new** array. As a consequence, repeated use of `+=` on arrays can be quite inefficient.
>
> See also [`#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-concat).

Compare to [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)

> ## `ary << obj` → `ary`
>
> Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of **this** array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.
>
> ```
> [ 1, 2 ] << "c" << "d" << [ 3, 4 ]
>         #=>  [ 1, 2, "c", "d", [ 3, 4 ] ]
> ```

The documentation of `Array#+` clearly says that a **new** array is returned (no less than four times, actually). This is consistent with other uses of the `+` method in Ruby, e.g. [`Bignum#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Bignum.html#method-i-2B), [`Fixnum#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B), [`Complex#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Complex.html#method-i-2B), [`Rational#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html#method-i-2B), [`Float#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-2B), [`Time#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-2B), [`String#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B), [`BigDecimal#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-2B), [`Date#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B), [`Matrix#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-2B), [`Vector#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-2B), [`Pathname#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-2B), [`Set#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-2B), and [`URI::Generic#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-2B).